# Can I copy a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database to a file?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to have a full copy of a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database from a server to my portable usb/hard disk and then transfer it into a new server that I will create. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use `pg_dump` to export a DB

Comment: ...and `pg_dumpall`!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html) or [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pg-dumpall.html) to export various parts of your database to a file which you can then use to restore to a different database using [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgrestore.html)

I was using pg_dump for a while to create backups of my database as we were preparing to move to a new server. When the new server was built, I simply took the latest pg_dump file, and loaded it into the new database using pg_restore, and we were up and running!